Como redirecionar cookies de uma API externa para o navegador usando Next.js 14 com App Router?
Estou enfrentando um problema ao tentar redirecionar cookies recebidos de uma API externa para o navegador. Estou usando Next.js versão 14 com o App Router. Quando faço uma solicitação para a API, ela retorna os cookies corretamente, mas eles não são definidos no navegador.
Aqui está um resumo do que estou fazendo:
Faço uma solicitação para a API externa usando fetch dentro de uma rota no Next.js.
A API externa responde com um conjunto de cookies.
Quero que esses cookies sejam definidos no navegador do usuário.
Como posso garantir que os cookies retornados pela API externa sejam corretamente enviados e definidos no navegador?
Agradeço qualquer ajuda!

Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.
